# DataGrid row added event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, datagrid

I know... this question was being asked a lot... but always with the same answer "put your logic in the viewmodel".

But in this example I have to put the logic in the view because I have to measure the size of each datagrid in my view every time the row count of one of them is changing. The problem is... in my viewmodel I don´t have access to the datagrid, so I can´t measure anything. And in my view I can´t get a response that the row count has changed.

Someone got an idea how I know in the view that a row was added or deleted in a datagrid?
It is a custom datagrid with a customtemplate btw. maybe that is going to help somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ObservableCollection` binded to the `DataGrid`, right? And you have a `ViewModel` (which contains that `ObservableCollection`) as the `DataContext` of the `View`. You may subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` within your view (you can access your ViewModel from your view, because it is the `View.DataContext`).

E.g.

```
(this.DataContext as ViewModel).YourCollection
    .CollectionChanged += (s, e) => { /* logic */ };
```

It slightly violates MVVM. If this is an absolutely custom control then you already receive the events from the `ObservableCollection` (because you need to update the UI) so you can handle this there.

Another approach I can think is to use some kind of `Mediator` pattern, e.g. `Messenger` in MVVMLight.

Comment: yea... but then it isn´t really MVVM conform I think? Because then the view depends ecplicit on this viewmodel. No way to avoid this? I mean... the datagrid itself has somehow to know if there was a row added to it... or am I wrong?

Comment: see my edits. btw in MVVM the view has knowledge of the ViewModel as it already depends on its properties, you can't just swap in any viewmodel.

Comment: from the given information these options comes to my mind but you may have several more, but I don't see the code.